# Match as many as possible and replace with one

Tags: regex, replace

I need a regex which matches as many as possible of the special characters `\` and `|`. I want to replace the matches with one special character afterwards. I know how to replace them, but I dont know the right regex to select as many as possible.

I tried some variations, but honestly I don't know what I'm doing and need some help.

```
[|+]|[\+]
```

Example data:

```
Hello ||||| this \\ is a test |||
```

Desired result:

```
Hello . this . is a test .
```

Comment: which regex family? sed, perl, python,m grep, $X?  You are probably looking for "greedy".

Comment: I will use it in java and c#. I don't know much about regex families.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring the `+` outside. Inside the character class it is just the `+` symbol. Also, escape the `\`:

```
[|]+|[\\]+
```

Also, since you are trying to replace them all with one char only, you may prefer the following regex:

```
[|\\]+
```

It will turn `Hello ||\\|| world` into `Hello . world`. Whereas the first would turn it into `Hello ... world`

See demo: http://regexr.com?35ef0

Comment: Thanks for the description. The regex [|\\]+ is exactly what i need and the link for testing it is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Javascript example):

```
"Hello ||||| this || is a test |||".replace(/[|]+|[\\]+/g, ".")
```

will output:

```
"Hello . this . is a test ."
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get what you want in Javascript.

```
'Hello ||||| this |\\| is a test |||'.replace(/(\||\\)+/g, ' . ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
"Hello ||||| this || is a test |||".replace(/\|+/g, ".");
```